# BeautifulSoup's .append doesn't seem to change the soup-object

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm modifying a BeautifulSoup-object but appending a tag does not seem to actually append the tag anywhere. Changing the name of a tag does work, but for some reason the .append doesn't. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The only reason I could think of was that the .append-functionality doesn't work in-place but instead creates a new copy but in the official documentation .append is used like it's in-place.

```
testclade = """
<phy:clade branch_length_attr="0.00576111248034">
    <phy:name>22316-6_AHCVY7AFXX_S13.27</phy:name>
    <phy:branch_length>5.761112e-03</phy:branch_length>
</phy:clade>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(testclade, 'xml')

clades = soup.find_all('clade')

for c in clades:
    if len(c.contents) == 5:
        print 'leaf clade detected, changing contents...'

        # create a tag to be added
        mouseovertag = soup.new_tag('annotation')

        # append the mouseovertag to the leaf-clade. 
        # This apparently does not work, the mouseovertag is nowhere to be seen
        c.append(mouseovertag)  

        # replace the name of the leaf clade. This does work!
        c.string = 'the changed name'

print soup.prettify()
```

Comment: I sort of figured it out, when I don't change c.string it does work

Answer (score 0):

If I am right in thinking that you want to add a new key-value pair to the `clade` xml element, the following gets the job done, though feels hacky.

```
c.attrs['annotation'] = 'the changed name'
```

It shows up in your call to `soup.prettify()` too.

---

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag) `.new_tag()` is for appending a *new* xml tag to the selected element rather than modifying existing elements.

Comment: I want to create a new tag and not change the attributes of an existing tag so this didn't help me a lot